# Require authorization for Swagger documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, grape-api

I'm using `grape`, `grape-swagger`, and `grape-swagger-rails` to set up an API for my Rails 4.2.1 project. It's going to be an internal API, so I want developers to be able to access it, but not the general public. What's the best way to do that?

My initial idea was to take advantage of the `api_key` field that you can set in `swagger-ui`, but I can't figure out the right way to access it inside the root API generator for Grape.

I also thought I could try to only mount the endpoint for the documentation if the user is an admin (we're using Devise), but that doesn't hide the documentation itself (if someone knows the `swagger.json` link).

How have people dealt with this problem in the past?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you asked for but it might interest some of you.

To keep swagger-ui in production, with a basic-auth:

```
# routes.rb
GrapeSwaggerRails::Engine.middleware.use Rack::Auth::Basic do |username, password|
  username == 'foo' && password == 'bar'
end if Rails.env.production?

mount GrapeSwaggerRails::Engine, at: "/swagger"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorcery` for authentication which adds several very handy methods (in the example below `logged_in?`) and in `config/initializers/swagger.rb` add:

```
GrapeSwaggerRails.options.before_filter do |request|
  unless logged_in?
    redirect_to Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_path
  end
end
```

Using `api_key` is also possible. In your `class API < Grape::API` just add `before` block where to check if the `api_key` value is correct, accessing it through `params`.

Comment: I actually couldn't seem to access `api_key` in `params` inside the initializer. I don't want to have to declare it as a parameter to every API method.

Comment: I didn't mean accessing `api_key` in one of your initializers but in a `before` block in `app/api/name/api.rb`. Like that there is no need to declare it as a parameter to every API method.